# How to remove the glossy highlight on selected UITabBarItem in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

By default in the UITabbar, there is a glossy highlight on the selected UITabBarItem.

Is it possible to remove the glossy highlight mask ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 58):

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Excellent answer, but be aware that this will affect ALL UITabBars, even ones that are subclasses.

Answer (score 6):

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage {anImage}]]
```

this has effect on every tabbar you use (even the subclassed ones)

If you use an image here that has the same colour as your tabbar background, you wont see an indicator.

Maybe you can even use an full transparent image, or an image that's 1px*1px.

Comment: Use http://ioscodesnippet.tumblr.com/post/9247898208/creating-a-placeholder-uiimage-dynamically-with-color to create the clear image. Works great.

Answer (score 5):

In case if you are customizing tab bar items with custom images, you may do such thing.
I made customizing tab bar items by adding background image to tab bar with all tabs drawn, one tab in selected state, and others in unselected state. In each didSelectViewController I change background image.
Than, I bring background image view to front, and add custom labels with needed title.

Result: I have customized tab bar with no glossy effect. Interesting is that UITabBarButtons are under background image, but still selectable.

The code is something like that:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self customizeTabBar];
}

- (void)customizeTabBar {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tabbg%i.png", tabBarCtrl.selectedIndex + 1];

    for(UIView *view in tabBarCtrl.tabBar.subviews) {  
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {  
            [view removeFromSuperview];  
        }  
    }  
    UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]] autorelease];
    [tabBarCtrl.tabBar insertSubview:background atIndex:0]; 
    [tabBarCtrl.tabBar bringSubviewToFront:background];
        //if needed, here must be adding UILabels with titles, I didn't need it.

}
```

Maybe you will be interested about this :)

Comment: in that UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>, which is implementing your tab bar controller's delegate. You need image for whole tab bar panel for each tab bar item, representing current item picture in selected state, and other in default state. According to selected tab index, background is replaced in - (void)customizeTabBar

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple´s Documentation you can implement :

```
(void)setFinishedSelectedImage:
      (UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:
      (UIImage *)unselectedImage
```

Which is a UITabBar method

[Here´s the link.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/setFinishedSelectedImage%3awithFinishedUnselectedImage%3a)