# Change the background color of "More" view controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to use an image or otherwise change the background color of cells in the "More" navigation controller of a UITabBarController?

Comment: As noted by travis duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar

Comment: No this is no duplicate!

Answer (score 7):

Neither of those links are the answer to this question.  It seems Malakim is referring to the MoreViewController of the `UITabBarController`, and not wanting to change the tabbar colors, but the cells that makeup the MoreViewController's tableView.

The answer is pretty easy.  You can reference the moreViewController property of your tabBarController which would give you a reference to an instance of a `UIMoreNavigationController`.

```
UINavigationController* moreNavController = myTabController.moreViewController;
```

With this navigation controller you then want the root view controller's view, because this is what is holding your tableView.  In fact, the root view controller is a `UITableViewController`, and accessing it's view grabs the tableView directly!

`UITableView* moreView = ((UIViewController*)[moreNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view;` //might need to cast here to suppress warnings

and thar ye go, moreView has a reference to hee tableView you are interested in.  You could then delve further by using moreView.subviews or just make an ugly background color change like `moreView.backgroundColor = [UIColor uglyColor];`

Comment: Additionally, you could take the tableView, and create an interceptor that overrides the (cellForRowAtIndexPath:) method (after passing it to the moreViewController first!).

Comment: Change to UINavigationController* moreNavController = myTabController.moreNavigationController;

Answer (score 1):

The method given by Steve works fine but it was giving me warning when i try to set the view of moreNavController to a table view.

```
warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct UIView *', expected 'struct UITableView *'
```

So inorder to remove the warnings i tried the below code and it works, not sure it is the proper way

```
    UINavigationController* moreNavController = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
    UIViewController* moreViewController = [moreNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; 
    moreViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```