# UITabBarController skin?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to skin the tab bar similarly to the Game Center tab bar? How so?

Comment: By the way, the game center skin looks like an inverted regular skin. (Like accessibility mode)

Comment: This [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar) may help you.