# UITabBar iPhone query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar

How do I change `UITabBar` selected or highlighted color in an iphone application?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Custom colors in UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that.  You will have to code your own tab bar.