# iPhone - tab bar kind of functionality

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I want to have colored images (not gray ones) in UITabbar view. But its not possible.
Also each tab, we can associate one view controller. The view controller can be a view or a navigation view or a table view. (Its simple to handle)

So, I decided to place 3 different buttons at the bottom of the view. On click of each button, I want to show different view controllers (in the space above 3 buttons). I don't want to use something like

```
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Do you want me to create 3 different view-controllers or views or something else and achieve the functionality of tab bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating tab bar functionality it will easy to handle creating custom tab bar class with Images. read this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar)

In this you set the image for background color using

([[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultad.png"]])