# How do I texture controls on iPhone Apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I would like to apply a texture to my iPhone app similar to the tab bar in GameCenter.app. Is there a good tutorial somewhere that explains this? I am hoping for a method that will translate easily to other controls as well. Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the control - Apple implements their drawing and layout differently.

Comment: Particularly I'm interested in Buttons, TabBars, and ListView's.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to add texture for backgrounds is to use the built in colorWithPatternImage.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundPattern"];
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

If you have a toolbar you should be able to use your "Patternized UIView" with UIBarButtonItem, one of its initializers take a UIView.

Comment: Thanks it worked btw i also found out how to do it with navbars http://foobarpig.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-or-image-background.html