# Custom UITabBarController SIGABRT crash in ios5 sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have this case where I am using a custom `UITabBar` in my application.
It is working great in ios4 on both device and simulator.

But running the same code using xcode 4.2 and ios5 sdk wont work, as the app is crashing when I am setting the view controllers of my custom `tabBarController` on this line:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc1, nc2, nc3, nil];
```

Here is how I am creating the tabBar:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    tabBarController = [[MBCustomTabBarController alloc] init];

    home=[[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nc1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];

    live=[[Live alloc] initWithNibName:@"Live" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nc2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:live];

    report=[[Report alloc] initWithNibName:@"Report" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nc3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:report];


    //custom tabbar items
    MBCustomTabBarItem *firstItem = [[MBCustomTabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"headlines" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HOME-.png"] tag:0];
    MBCustomTabBarItem *secondItem = [[MBCustomTabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"live" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NEWS-.png"] tag:1];
    MBCustomTabBarItem *thirdItem = [[MBCustomTabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"report" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"REPORT-.png"] tag:2];


    [firstItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HOME.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [secondItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NEWS.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [thirdItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"REPORT.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    nc1.tabBarItem=firstItem;
    nc2.tabBarItem=secondItem;
    nc3.tabBarItem=thirdItem;

    [firstItem release];
    [secondItem release];
    [thirdItem release];


    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc1, nc2, nc3, nil];
    [nc1 release];
    [nc2 release];
    [nc3 release];
    tabBarController.customTabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480 - 49, 320, 49);
    tabBarController.customTabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tabBarController.customTabBar.itemWidth = 320 / [self.tabBarController.viewControllers count];


    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

And [here](http://www.foo-apps.net/testCustomTabBar/testCustomTabBar.zip) is a small working example.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've totally changed my approach and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar/6546767#6546767) answer to build my custom tabBar. And it is working fine under ios5.