# Transparent/translucent navigation bar with button items in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I'm trying to get an almost transparent navigation bar. But I don't want the buttons on it to be transparent.

This is my code:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.3
```

This does make it translucent but it also makes the buttons translucent/faded. How can I have a translucent bar but still have the buttons opaque?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082963/how-to-make-completely-transparent-navigation-bar-in-ios-7

Comment: this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431976/visible-buttons-with-transparent-navigation-bar

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for the links, the second one seems to address my problem, but I don't know objective c, do you know of any swift examples?

Comment: sure i will do which one you need can you add, I will modfied to swift

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik actually I found a good enough answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent That still doesn't make it translucent, but it does make it fully transparent which works for me for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

Comment: Forget to say don't set alpha for `navigationBar`

Comment: You sure this will keep the buttons still visible?

Comment: Yeah tried it, it keeps the buttons visible, but doesn't make the bar black. It just keeps it as the default color. Tint color is the one that seems to affect the color of the navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3) 
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor() 
navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Makes it black, but does not make it transparent.