# How can I change the tab bar selection color instead of blue?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Normally tab bar selection color is blue in iPhone. Instead of that I want to change the color as brown. How can I change the tabbar selection color? Shall I need to create custom tabbar controller?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes if you create customTabBar controller and switch background image of TabBar control then its work like system TabBar...you just create 5 different images and set it with selected tab on your TabBar Delegate method,here if you use graphics image then its also work.....means you use this tabbar globally in your many application
:)

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to use an image:

> [self.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_tab.png"]];

In case you want to use a color:

> [self.tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Answer (score 2):

```
tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Its only changing the tab bar color, but i need to change selection color.

Comment: I tried but its only changing the tab bar color, Not changing the selection color

Comment: inside the viewdidload method

Comment: set it where u are initializing settings of tabbar

Comment: @Subramanian did you find a solution ? Whatever I find, it changes the color of whole tab bar, I want to have different color for selected tab and different for unselected.