# iOS 7 - Disable UITabBarItem tint color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar with five icons, most of them being flat with just one color. However, one of these buttons should not have a tint color, since it's the company's logo and the logo has various different colors. I know it's possible to to so  with UINavigationBar and UIToolbar (which is what I'm using and it's a horrible workaround).

I did some heavy searching and tried many different solutions (I came up with with some crazy ones too), but none of them seem to work for me o iOS 7. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve that?

Thanks a million!

Comment: This might be useful


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar

Comment: The solution suggested on that thread doesn't solve my problem, although one of the answers is about doing what Kaszás suggested below. Anyway, thanks for helping

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use ImageWithRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.

```
UIImage *icon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also create 'Image Asset' and set it there in the 'Attributes Inspector' tab.

[image]