# iOS Tab item fuzzy image

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbaritem, xcode8

The size of the original fuzzier image(tab2) is 2x: 108 × 88 pixels, 3x: 162 × 132 pixels, the normal image(tab1, tab3) size is 2x: 52 × 48 pixels, 3x: 78 × 72 pixels. I run the app on iPhone7 simulator with iOS 10, Xcode 8.1, the result:
[image: fuzzy result]

The original image:
[image: original image]

I also changed the setting of the Tab item as below:
[image: setting]

What's wrong with me? I'd like to set it as below:

[image: result]

Comment: Try change the image's render mode to original

Comment: this probably cause by the tint color applied by the tabbar, this SO may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032134/ios-7-disable-uitabbaritem-tint-color

Comment: Set image transparency in image editing software comapre your tab bar one & three image with second one

Comment: @Tj3n thanks man, I've fixed this as your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this question as @Tj3n's suggestion, please refer to the below pic which I've marked a red rectangle:
[image]